# Export each person in CSV file to an XAML file using a BAT script

Tags: xaml, batch-file, csv

i've been given a CSV file called 'people.csv' and need to export each person in the file to it's own XAML file... the CSV looks like this

"name", "job title"

"Rich Bishop", "Owner"

"Liam Smythe", "Apprentice"

"Josh Middleton", "Human-Computer Hybrid"

And i need to write a BAT file that exports each of those names and job titles into their own XAML file, so my end result should be richbishop.xaml, liamsmythe.xaml and so on...

Output format for the XAML:

```
<Grid Background="Red" x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,0,12,0"> 
  <StackPanel Margin="20" Background="Blue" PointerPressed="commonHandler"> 
    <TextBlock x:Name="firstTextBlock" FontSize="30" >** NAME </TextBlock> 
    <TextBlock x:Name="secondTextBlock" FontSize="30" > JOB TITLE **</TextBlock>
  </StackPanel> 
</Grid>
```

Comment: Josh Middleton from Sylosis? Anyway - SO is not a write-your-code-for-you site - please include some info on what you have already tried and where you are getting stuck (I'm thinking that a batch file probably won't cut it here but maybe I'm wrong... I've seen some impressive batch files in my time!). Are you sure you want XAML too? Can you give some background info...

Comment: I didnt ask for someone to write the code for me, i just want some clues to what im supposed to do because i have no idea :-S I've been given a challenge and just want putting in the right direction

Comment: specify your output format! XAML what?

Comment: <Grid Background="Red" x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <StackPanel Margin="20" Background="Blue" PointerPressed="commonHandler">
        <TextBlock x:Name="firstTextBlock" FontSize="30" >** NAME **</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="secondTextBlock" FontSize="30" >** JOB TITLE **</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>

Comment: It needs to look like that but instead of **JOB TITLE** and **NAME** it should have the persons name and their job title...

Comment: Edit your question and show the formatted xaml text in your question.

Answer (score 1):

See how this works for you:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,* delims=," %%a in (people.csv) do (
set "name=%%~a" & set "job=%%b"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set namexaml=!name: =!
set job=!job:~2,-1!
echo "!name!" "!job!"
(
echo ^<Grid Background="Red" x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,0,12,0"^> 
echo  ^<StackPanel Margin="20" Background="Blue" PointerPressed="commonHandler"^> 
echo    ^<TextBlock x:Name="firstTextBlock" FontSize="30" ^>!NAME!^</TextBlock^> 
echo    ^<TextBlock x:Name="secondTextBlock" FontSize="30" ^>!JOB!^</TextBlock^>
echo   ^</StackPanel^> 
echo ^</Grid^>
)>"!namexaml!.xaml"
endlocal
)
pause
```